# Bash script for testing a program

Tags: c, bash, automated-tests

This is a trivial program that reverses a string.

```
void str_reverse(const char*, size_t, char*, size_t);

int main(){

    char str[256];

    while(fgets(str, 256, stdin)){
        if(strncasecmp(str, "quit", 4) == 0) break;

        size_t size_reversed = strlen(str) * sizeof(char);
        char* reversed = malloc(size_reversed);
        str_reverse(str, sizeof(str), reversed, size_reversed);
        printf("Orginal String : %s\n", str);
        printf("Reversed String : %s\n", reversed);
        printf("__________________________________\n");
        free(reversed);
    }
    return 0;
}

void str_reverse(const char* str1, size_t size1, char* str2, size_t size2){

    memcpy(str2, str1, size1);

    char temp;
    size_t len = strlen(str2) - 1;
    size_t stop = len/2;
    size_t i,k;

    for(i = 0, k = len; i < stop; i++, k--)
    {
        temp = str2[k];
        str2[k] = str2[i];
        str2[i] = temp;
    }
    //return str;
}
```

I'm trying to foray into writing a bash script to automate the compilation and testing of this program. I have the following test cases in mind:

- Normal string,
- Empty string,
- Numbers,
- Mixed cases

Can someone help me get started with this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a makefile?

Comment: Your question is somewhat broad. What did you try? What kind of errors did you run into? Which resources/tutorials did you read? Please add at least some of this information to the question, and point out the specific problem you encountered, or the instructions you misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the program to accept the string to reverse as a command line argument and then print the reversed string as an output. Then, use a bash script to compare the output of the program against expected output.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   if ( argc != 2 )
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Expect to see one argument.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   char* str = argv[1];

   size_t size_reversed = strlen(str) * sizeof(char);
   char* reversed = malloc(size_reversed+1);
   str_reverse(str, strlen(str), reversed, size_reversed);
   printf("%s\n", reversed);
   free(reversed);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function test_program()
{
   in="$1"
   expected_out="$2"
   out=$(./program "$in")

   if [ "$out" != "$expected_out" ]
   then
      echo "output: $out"
      echo "expected output: $expected_out"
      echo "Test failed."
   else
      echo "Test passed"
   fi
}

test_program "automate the compilation" "noitalipmoc eht etamotua"
test_program "compilation" "noitalipmoc"
test_program "abcd" "dcba"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc source -o xname
echo "teststring" | ./xname
echo "teststring2" | ./xname
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BATS](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) for automated testing. This is great tool to automate testing.

[bats-core](/questions/tagged/bats-core)

Answer (score 1):

After adding the necessary include files,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

you can use a script like below,

```
#!/bin/bash

# Compile reverse.c
make reverse

# Declare and feed test strings
declare -a string_array=("" "string" "12345" "string STRING")

for str in ${string_array[@]}
do
    echo "$str" | ./reverse
done
```